# Powershell with Git Command Error Handling - automatically abort on non-zero exit code from external program

Tags: git, powershell, error-handling, teamcity, exit-code

I use Git to deploy my web application. So in Teamcity I prepare my application (compilation, minify JS and HTML, delete unused files, etc...) and then I have a Powershell build step :

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
git init
git remote add origin '%env.gitFolder%'
git fetch
git reset --mixed origin/master
git add .
git commit -m '%build.number%'
git push origin master
```

But if an exception throw, the script continue (even if I set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`) and the build is successful.

I want the script to stop when there is an error, and the build to failed.

I tried to put `Format stderr output as: error` on the build step and `Fail build if: an error message is logged by build runner`, so the build failed, but the script continue, and so it's creating an stupid commit.

I try to put a try-catch in my script, but it doesn't enter in the catch...

Does anyone have an idea to stop the script and failed the build on error ?

Sorry for my English, I'm French... ^^

Comment: TeamCity's handling of Powershell errors isn't very intuitive. I've previously given [this piece of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165278/1540600) - but you're saying that Try/Catch aren't helping.

Answer (score 26):

The **`$ErrorActionPreference` variable does *not* apply to calling *external utilities*** ([console] applications) such as `git`, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x

- A potential *future enhancement* is being discussed in [RFC #277](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/277/files), for
  proper integration of calls to external programs into PowerShell's error-handling.

There are only **two ways to *determine* success vs. failure of an external utility**:

- By examining the **automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable**, which PowerShell sets to the ***exit code* reported by the external utility**.
  By convention, a value of **`0` indicates *success***, whereas any ***nonzero* value indicates *failure***. (Do note that some utilities, e.g., `robocopy.exe`, use certain nonzero exit codes to communicate non-error conditions too.)
- If you're not interested in the *specific* exit code reported, you can examine the ***Boolean* automatic variable `$?`**, which reflects `$True` for exit code `0`, and `$False` for any nonzero exit code.

  - **[Fixed in PowerShell 7.2+]** **Caveats**: As of PowerShell (Core) 7.1, there are two ***bugs***; both these are tentatively fixed via the `PSNotApplyErrorActionToStderr` *experimental feature* (!) in *preview* versions of 7.2 (all experimental features are turned on by default in newly installed preview versions).

    - `$?` can falsely reflect `$false` when `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0` *and* a stderr redirection (`2>` or `*>`) is used *and* the command emitted stderr output (which in itself doesn't necessarily indicate failure) - see [GitHub issue #10512](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10512).

      - **It is therefore a good habit to form to query only `$LASTEXITCODE`, not `$?` to infer failure vs. succcess.**
    - If `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `'Stop'` and you happen to use `2>` or `*>` with an external program and that program produces actual stderr output, `$ErrorActionPreference` unexpectedly *does* apply and causes a script-terminating error (whether or not the external program signals actual failure via a nonzero *exit code*) - see [GitHub issue #4002](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002)
- If you want to *capture* stderr output lines, you have to redirect them to a *file* as of PowerShell 7.2.x (e.g., `2>errs.txt`; see caveat above re PowerShell 7.1 and below); [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332) suggests introducing a syntax that allows *in-memory* capturing, in a *variable*. However, there is an *indirect* way of capturing them in memory, namely by merging stderr into the success output stream with `2>&1`, which allows you to filter lines that came from stderr by the *.NET type* of the objects in the success output stream - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106198/45375).

***Acting* on a failure requires *explicit* action**, typically by using the `Throw` keyword to generate a script-terminating error.

---

Clearly, checking `$LASTEXITCODE` / `$?` after every external-utility call is cumbersome, so here's a **wrapper function** that facilitates this process:

**Note**: While this function works, it does *not* try to compensate for the [broken-up-to-at-least-v7.2.x passing of arguments with embedded double quotes to external programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375). To get this compensation, you can use the **`iee` function from the [Native module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)**, installable from the PowerShell Gallery via `Install-Module Native`.

```
function Invoke-Utility {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Invokes an external utility, ensuring successful execution.

.DESCRIPTION
Invokes an external utility (program) and, if the utility indicates failure by 
way of a nonzero exit code, throws a script-terminating error.

* Pass the command the way you would execute the command directly.
* Do NOT use & as the first argument if the executable name is not a literal.

.EXAMPLE
Invoke-Utility git push

Executes `git push` and throws a script-terminating error if the exit code
is nonzero.
#>
  $exe, $argsForExe = $Args
  # Workaround: Prevents 2> redirections applied to calls to this function
  #             from accidentally triggering a terminating error.
  #             See bug report at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
  try { & $exe $argsForExe } catch { Throw } # catch is triggered ONLY if $exe can't be found, never for errors reported by $exe itself
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { Throw "$exe indicated failure (exit code $LASTEXITCODE; full command: $Args)." }
}
```

Now you just need to prepend `Invoke-Utility`  to all your `git` calls, and if any of them reports a nonzero exit code, the script is aborted.

If that is too verbose, define an alias for your function: `Set-Alias iu Invoke-Utility`, in which case you only need to prepend `iu` :

```
iu git init
iu git remote add origin '%env.gitFolder%'
iu git fetch
# ...
```

Comment: For some native programs in powershell 7.0.3 `$LASTEXITCODE` reports non zero at the same time as `$?` reports True. https://i.imgur.com/4P9au0c.png on this screenshot, `packer` is [packer](https://www.packer.io/).

Comment: And just now I realised what's happening - both packer and go is installed with [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) which creates a shim around the executable. The shim is `.ps1` which affects the results. Case closed.

Comment: @EvilNeo, please see my update, but the short of it is: As of PS 7.1 there is no _direct_ way of capturing them in a variable; you need to save to a file first. A future enhancement may remedy this. An _indirect_ way is to merge stderr into the success output stream with `2>&1` and then identify the stderr lines in the output streams by their .NET type.

Comment: If we use `iee` do we still need to check `$LASTEXITCODE` or something else to make the script fail?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, no, `iee` automatically uses `throw` to raise a script-terminating (fatal) error if `$LASTEXITCODE` is nonzero. Try `iee cmd /c exit 1; "this won't print"`, for instance.

Answer (score 14):

I believe the problem here is that the error thrown by `git` is not trappable by PS.

Illustration:

```
try {
    git push
    Write-Host "I run after the git push command"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Something went wonky"
}
```

[image: Note the missing <code>Write-Host</code> from the <code>catch</code> block!]

Note the missing `Write-Host` from the `catch` block!

This is where we need to look at the exit code of the git commands.

The easiest way (I know) in PowerShell is to check the value of `$?` (more information on `$?` here: [What is `$?` in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634115/what-is-in-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
try {
    git push
    if (-not $?) {
        throw "Error with git push!"
    }
    Write-Host "I run after the git push command"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Something went wonky"
    throw
}
```

[image: Check our custom error (now caught by the <code>catch</code> block)!]

Check our custom error (now caught by the `catch` block)!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation !
But, like I have many lines in my powershell script, I can't do that on every lines, it will be unreadable...

Comment: If readability is your concern; create a wrapper function that does the "error handling" for you. Functionality is more important than readability. But yes; maintainability should always maintain a prominent position!

Comment: You can one-line your check if that helps: `if ($?) {throw}`