# Automatically abort PowerShell script when external process returns a non-zero exit code

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exit-code

When creating a bash script, we can use `set -e` to say that the script should be aborted when anything fails. In PowerShell, we have something similar with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. For example, if I create a script like this:

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
SomeUnkownCommand
Write-Host "I don't want this line to be executed because previous line failed"
```

Then, the `Write-Host` command will not be executed.

But if I have a script like this that calls an **external process**:

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$output = & sc.exe stop some_unknown_service
Write-Host "I don't want this line to be executed because previous line failed"
```

Then, the `Write-Host` command **is** executed and the script completes without any error.

If I don't want my script to continue after the external process fails, I must do something like this:

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$output = & sc.exe stop some_unknown_service
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) 
{
    throw "External process failed with code $LASTEXITCODE"
}
Write-Host "I don't want this line to be executed because previous line failed"
```

This makes the code much less readable since I have to put these `if` all over my code.

Just like `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in PowerShell and `set -e` in bash, is there a way to tell PowerShell to raise an error as soon as any external process fails?

Comment: In short: as of PowerShell 7.0, this is not directly supported, unfortunately, but changing that has been proposed: see the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877892/45375) for background info and a workaround via a small helper function.

Comment: However, here are the same results shown in your post without if - try/catch or ErrorActionPreference

Write-Host 'Before command and error throw' -ForegroundColor Yellow
SomeUnkownCommand
throw $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0
Write-Warning -Message 'After error throw'

Before command and error throw
SomeUnkownCommand : The term 'SomeUnkownCommand' is ...

Write-Host 'Before command and error throw' -ForegroundColor Yellow
$output = & sc.exe stop some_unknown_service
throw $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0
Write-Warning -Message 'After throw'

Before command and error throw
True
At line:4 ...