# PowerShell not terminating with $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Tags: powershell

I'm running some python code that is exiting via `sys.exit(1)` when failures occur.  However, PowerShell (which is calling this code) doesn't terminate, even though I've told it to.

Example code that illustrates the issue:

```
python -c "import sys; sys.exit(1)"
Write-Host "The exit code is $LASTEXITCODE -- why is this running?"
```

What am I missing here?

I'm launching the code via:

`.\test.ps1`

(for example)

PowerShell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  145
```

Comment: In short: `$ErrrorActionPreference` has no effect on calling _external programs_; check `$LASTEXITCODE` to determine success vs. failure and report an error in response; see [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877892/45375) for details.