# Powershell: Issue redirecting output from error stream when using docker

Tags: docker, powershell, powershell-core

I am working on a set of build scripts which are called from a ubuntu hosted CI environment. The powershell build script calls `jest` via `react-scripts` via `npm`. Unfortunately jest doesn't use `stderr` correctly and writes non-errors to the stream.

I have redirected the error stream using `3>&1 2>&1` and this works fine from just powershell core (`$LASTEXITCODE` is 0 after running, no content from stderr is written in red).

However when I introduce docker via `docker run`, the build script appears to not behave and outputs the line that should be redirected from the error stream in red (and crashes). i.e. something like: `docker : PASS src/App.test.js. Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? because I'm a bit stumped. I include the sample PowerShell call below:-

```
function Invoke-ShellExecutable
{
    param (
        [ScriptBlock]
        $Command
    )

    $Output = Invoke-Command $Command -NoNewScope | Out-String

    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        $CmdString = $Command.ToString().Trim()
        throw "Process [$($CmdString)] returned a failure status code [$($LASTEXITCODE)]. The process may have outputted details about the error."
    }

    return $Output
}

Invoke-ShellExecutable { 
  ($env:CI = "true") -and (npm run test:ci)
} 3>&1 2>&1
```

Comment: Don't use `-and`: it'll only ever return `$true` or `$false`, and your `npm` call's output will be lost - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375). Also note that your environment variable definition will linger. If you `throw` before returning output, you won't be able to inspect the output. Move the redirection (`2>&1` will do) inside the `Invoke-ShellExecutable` call, to `Invoke-Command`. More simply, use `$Output = . $Command 2>&1 | Out-String`. (Or use the more typical `&` instead of `.`, as scoping doesn't apply to _external programs_.)

Comment: Thanks this helped me get to my answer. There was also an interaction with $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" which was present at the top of the file. Which seems to get reset even when you force no new scope.

I really don't understand why exit behaviour and error behaviour have any affect on how stderr error is reported to the console.

Comment: Glad to hear it. As for the surprising interaction between `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and stderr output from external programs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877892/45375).